What film is it where the antagonist uses an expandable triple knife?
I am looking for a movie in which a special dagger appears. In the scene, the villain shows the protagonist a collection of weapons and elements of torture, with special emphasis on this dagger.
It is a kind of dagger that is placed in the hand, with a mechanism that, when operated, causes the blade to split into three blades (preferably inside the enemy), thus causing greater damage and destruction.
One possibility is some James Bond movie, but I can't be sure about this.

Katar? https://www.maynardsfineart.com/auction-lot/an-indo-persian-scissor-katar-dagger_6614615AFE aka punching knife. Turns up in jungle book, amongst others. Not quite james bond though. Its a real knife though, from India, that splits and expands into three blades...

Also a longer version in grimm https://grimm.fandom.com/wiki/Three_Bladed_Knife

When did you watch this film?

Please check the tag you used to see how you can improve your question. There are very likely more details you can [edit] in.

I think it might be The Jungle Book, 1994:


 at 58:00 into the movie.
transcript:

uh this one is a personal favorite of mine
you um you thrust it into your opponent's belly like that you see
(clank sound as blade splits open at the press of a button)
and then you twist it a little and you rip out his stomach

This seems to match the OP's recollection:

In the scene the villain shows the protagonist a collection of weapons and elements of torture, with special emphasis on this dagger.



It is a kind of dagger that is placed in the hand, with a mechanism that when operated causes the blade to split into three blades



(preferably inside the enemy) thus causing greater damage and destruction.

And Cary Elwes is playing the villain here...
Background:
Katar https://www.maynardsfineart.com/auction-lot/an-indo-persian-scissor-katar-dagger_6614615AFE aka punching knife.
It does exist as a real knife/dagger, though in many non-opening variants.
It appears the opening variant might just be a ceremonial version rather than a real weapon as its operation makes it somewhat weaker than a single bladed weapon.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katar_(dagger)
Might also be called an Indian Death Scissor.

A fantastic find. Well done

Thanks a lot! It's exactly what I was looking for, I can sleep well now. Thanks again!
